# How to solve this algebraic manipulation problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Express the following expression $$E=(x^3-y^3)(y^3-z^3)(z^3-x^3)$$ in terms of $a, b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and 
$$a=x^2y+y^2z+z^2x$$ $$b=xy^2+yz^2+zx^2$$

Comment: Have you tried multiplying it out?

Comment: Yes, that’s right, I’ve wrote it wrong, my bad.

Comment: But how it could be solved, tho?

Comment: @RossMillikan already done that, it s just a mess a lot of powers and variable that doesn’t make sense in the end, it’s just a dead end.

Comment: Oh, come on people, this is really hard one. A specialy for someone new in this field.

Comment: @greedoid indeed it’s hard, but it s a trick somewhere, somehow.... but tho the exercise it s taken from a math contest, where usually the exercise are not that hard at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, we use $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$ for $(x,y)=(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)$ and we obtain
$$E=(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)(x^2+xy+y^2)(y^2+yz+z^2)(x^2+xz+z^2)$$
$$E=(x^2z+y^2x+z^2y-x^2y-y^2z-z^2x)(x^2+xy+y^2)(y^2+yz+z^2)(x^2+xz+z^2)$$
$$E=(b-a)(x^2+xy+y^2)(y^2+yz+z^2)(x^2+xz+z^2)=(b-a)E^{'}$$
$$\text{Let's say }c=\frac{a}{xyz}=\frac{x}{z} + \frac {y}{x} + \frac {z}{y} \text{and  }d=\frac{b}{xyz}=\frac{x}{y} + \frac {y}{z} + \frac {z}{x}$$
$$\frac{E^{'}}{(xyz)^2}=\prod_{cyc}{(x/yz+1/z+y/xz)}=(\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^2}{y^2}  + 2 * \sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{z}) + ( \sum_{cyc} \frac{x^2}{z^2} + 2* \sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{y} ) + (\sum {xy/z^2} +3 ) $$ 
$$\text{Therefore, }\frac{E^{'}}{(xyz)^2}=c^2 + d^2 + cd=\frac{a^2+b^2+ab}{(xyz)^2}$$
$$\text{Now we have obtained }E^{'}=a^2+b^2+ab\text{, and we know, from earlier, }E=(b-a)E^{'}\text{, therefore}$$
$$E=(b-a)(a^2+b^2+ab) $$
$$E=b^3-a^3 $$

Comment: That is, $E=b^3-a^3$

Comment: Indeed, thank you, I have added that now (at your suggestion).

Comment: I multiplied out $E$ and guessed the answer.  I was trying to work out a way to prove it without doing all the multiplications, or resorting to a CAS, when you posted your answer.  I may continue trying, though.

Comment: Thank’s a lot, I thought through this way but I believed it will be a dead end, and I drop it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Start: $$ a-b = xy(x-y)+yz (y-z)+zx(z-x) $$
$$= xy(x-y)+yz (y-z)+zx(z-\color{red}y)+zx(\color{red}y-x) $$
$$= (xy-zx)(x-y)+(yz -zx)(y-z)$$

$$ =x(y-z)(x-y)+z(y-x)(y-z) $$
$$ = (x-y)(y-z)(x-z)$$

So $$ E = (a-b)\underbrace{(x^2+xy+y^2)(y^2+yz+z^2)(z^2+zx+x^2)}_{A}$$

Now you have to figer out $A$. (I bet it is $3ab$.)

Comment: bro, it looks suspicious idk what to say about that A being 3ab

Comment: Did you calculate $A$. What about $3ab$?

Comment: I haven’t calculated A, cause it s a lot to process in and I think the answer to this question it s more elegant that all of those variables, idk I already try your version. That s why I m saying.

Comment: Please do cacluate $A$ and $3ab$ in OP othervise I will also vote for close.

Comment: @greedoid It is not 3ab. I've checked.